# Firebase config breaks when `projectId` is from environment variable

Tags: firebase, next.js, environment-variables, vercel

I'm experiencing a *really* odd issue with my Firebase config object and Vercel environment variables.

I can build up my entire Firebase config object with Vercel  environment variables but if I use an environment variable for the value of `projectId` it breaks the entire configuration.

My config follows this format:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: `${process.env.FIREBASE_apiKEY}`,
    authDomain: `${process.env.FIREBASE_authDomain}`,
    projectId: "my-project-id-here",
    storageBucket: `${process.env.FIREBASE_storageBucket}`,
    messagingSenderId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_messagingSenderId}`,
    appId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_appId}`,
    measurementId: `${process.env.FIREBASE_measurementId}`
};
```

I then initialize Firebase with the object like so:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

The above works, yet if I change the value of `projecId` to

```
`${process.env.FIREBASE_projectId}`
```

to match the others, I get `FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

I've verified the value of `process.env.FIREBASE_projectId` is correct in the `.env` file and that the value comes out correct in `firebaseConfig`, yet the only time I don't get the error is when I hard code the value in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using nextjs, use `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix for your environment variables

```
 const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APIKEY}`,
   authDomain: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN}`,
   projectId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECTID}`,
   storageBucket: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET}`,    
   messagingSenderId:`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID}`,
   appId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APPID}`,
   measurementId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID}`
     };
```

Comment: Wouldn't that expose all that sensitive information?